# How to set Euler rotation order in vector rotate node?

Tags: shaders, mathematics, shader-nodes, vector, vector-mapping

The vector rotate node has a `Euler` mode. My first problem is that it doesn't state what the Euler rotation order it uses. XYZ? ZYX? YZX?, which is it?

My second problem is that I want to change which rotation order it uses however changing the Euler rotation order in the viewport doesn't change the Euler rotation order of the `vector rotate node`.

So how would you do that?

Comment: There is something nice called API

Comment: Could you please explain what you are talking about?

Comment: You will find here:https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html
in the bpy section, what the function you use in the blender UI refer to, and will get insight on the order of the rotation ops.

Comment: @Yvain I am talking about the **vector rotate node** not the UI.

Comment: Yeah right and nodes are not part of the ui...

Comment: Oh you see the order is x y z

Comment: And how do I change that order?

Comment: @tempdevnova doesn't look like you can change it. It's XYZ in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/vector_rotate.html). Don't mind the image, they made a mistake.